# Where does GHCi search for DLLs?

Tags: windows, haskell, dll, ghci

When I do `stack repl` it fails to find the DLLs for a library that my project uses. I can fix this by placing them in the root of my package but this is unsatisfactory since I'd like them to be separated from my package.

Where does GHCi look for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer here https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-invocation.html

Apparently GHCi searches the standard search path of the OS.

Comment: can you please close/delete this question? Or restate it so it shows the actual problem? As it is it won't be of any use to future people searching for answers

Comment: @Carsten I'll try to restate it so it serves some purpose. This information wasn't really in plain sight so maybe it will save someone some time in the future

Comment: Just a note, this isn't the entire answer. GHCi (since 7.10.3) also searches the included mingw-w64 bindist folder and any and all extra-lib-dirs. a package specified in it's .cabal file.